# Change choice field of model in django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have multiple field choice in my model. I want to change the value of statue in my view. I read These [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) and  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726476/django-multiple-choice-field-checkbox-select-multiple).In those link, 2 way assumed:

> 1. create another model
> 2. MultipleChoiceField

What I must do, If I want to use MultipleChoiceField? I read these links: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) , [2](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2753/), [3](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) ,[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664672/get-a-multiple-choice-queryset-in-django-view-and-save-it), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464051/django-set-field-choices-from-view) ,and [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156162/change-choices-attribute-of-models-field) ;but non of them cloud help me and I can't understand anything.
Also this is my codes:

```
#models.py
STATUE_CHOICE = (
        ('draft', 'draft'),
        ('future', 'future'),
        ('trash', 'trash'),
        ('publish', 'publish'),
    )
statue = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUE_CHOICE)

#views.ppy
def delete_admin_trash_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    if request.method =="POST":
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        post.statue = 'trash'
        post.save()    
        return redirect('view_admin_post')
    else:
        form = AddPostForm(instance=post)
    template = 'blog/admin_blog/delete_admin_trash_post.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Is it possible to explain this method in a simple and complete way?

Comment: This should probably be a `ChoiceField`, not a `MultipleChoiceField`, since you can probably make only a *single* status.

Comment: I realy didn't understand anything about way 2 .So maybe it's common for me to write the name of the second method incorrectly. And another notice that: What is single statues ? And Does this meet my need? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MultipleChoiceField is a form widget. so you should use it in forms. widgets are ready to use HTML inputs that have some validators that validates and cleans data. to create a form just make a new file named forms.py (this is a common way to add a new file. you can just do this in views.py) then create a form with that.
by default, charfields model with choices has ChoiceField widget. if you want to override it you can do it in form Meta class. you have a model named Post:

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
      STATUE_CHOICE = (
              ('draft', 'draft'),
              ('future', 'future'),
              ('trash', 'trash'),
              ('publish', 'publish'),
          )
      statue = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUE_CHOICE)
      .
      .
```

and a form AddPostForm:

```
# forms.py
# or
# views.py
from .models import Post

class AddPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ('statue',...)
            widgets = {'statue' : forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Post.STATUE_CHOICE)}
```

this article can be useful :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Thanks. And what about `views.py` ? ِDoes `delete_admin_trash_post`  need any edits? @lost-gost

Comment: No.just in forms.

Comment: I tested it.It does not work! I think that `views.py` need some edit. @lost-gost

Comment: As I know it is ok with views.make sure you imported form.follow link that I said.it shows complete guide.and check your template.

Comment: I saw the link and I'm sure that the form is being imported to my file too. Is it possible to write the sample template in your answer?I think that template or views is the source of the problems! @lost-gost

Comment: Ahhhaaaa! Your answer was correct! I forgot to put `post.save()` in my method!Thanks for everything! :) @lost-gost